# Canvas Size Adjustment

Tags: python, tkinter

When my following code is executed, the only problem so far is that the canvas that shows up is only big enough to hold my "Go" button and my listbox, whereas I'm trying to set the perimeter with `width=700` and `height=200`. How would I adjust the code to make it so that my canvas always pops up to the determined size?

```
import tkinter

def main():
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    cv = tkinter.Canvas(root, width=700, height=200)
    cv.pack()

    root.title("Shakespeare Word Generator")

    g = tkinter.Button (cv,text ="Go", command = calculate_go)

    g.pack()

    Lb1 = tkinter.Listbox(cv, height=5, width=15)
    Lb1.insert(1, "Noun ")
    Lb1.insert(2, "Verb")
    Lb1.insert(3, "Adjective")
    Lb1.insert(4, "Adverb")

    Lb1.pack()

def calculate_go():
    print ("Finding Word...")


tkinter.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: First: why do you put `Button` and `ListBox` on `Canvas` - `Canvas` is rather for images - use `Frame` or put that widget directly on `root`. Second use arguments in `pack()`. You could also try to set window size.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you put `Button` and `Listbox` on `Canvas`?
Canvas is rather for images - use Frame or put that widget directly on root.

I don't use `Canvas` in my example

Use `root.geometry('700x200')` to set window size.

You can use `pack(fill=tk.X)` to resize widget lef/right if you need it.

`pack()` can do more so read about [Pack/Grid/Place Geometry Manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-index.htm#class-reference)

```
import tkinter as tk

def calculate_go():
    print ("Finding Word...")

def main():

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Shakespeare Word Generator")
    root.geometry('700x200')

    g = tk.Button (root,text ="Go", command = calculate_go)
    g.pack(fill=tk.X)

    Lb1 = tk.Listbox(root, height=5, width=15)
    Lb1.insert(1, "Noun ")
    Lb1.insert(2, "Verb")
    Lb1.insert(3, "Adjective")
    Lb1.insert(4, "Adverb")

    Lb1.pack()

    tkinter.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```